# Declaring 'const' works when implementing this inferface but 'let' does not? Why?

Tags: typescript

I come across a strange question here:
Why is `const` working, but `let` not working here?
[image]

```
interface Foo<T> {
    (arg: T): void;
    id: T;
}
const foo: Foo<number> = function(x) { console.log(foo.id+x); } //now this works
// let foo: Foo<number> = function(x) { console.log(foo.id+x); } // why can't we change const to let?
foo.id = 100;
foo(2);
```

Comment: Different syntax different results. `const` vars are easier to track because you don't have to track mutation. I guess since function declarations allow adding of props, `const` function were also allowed this behavior since they are similar enough.

Comment: It seems to me that neither should work, unless `id` is made optional. The constant `foo` right after instatiation lacks `id`, and therefore does not match its `interface`.

Comment: @tromgy you are correct, i did try making it optional before without problem, but that is a different story...